# handling an incoming call through an app in iphone xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, phone-call

My requirement from a client is to handle incoming calls of iphone, in such a way that any unwanted calls (such as any call that is outside from the address book) should go terminate automatically with just one ring and should go into missed calls.

i.e, i need an app that runs in background, detects every incoming call and if the call is from outside the address book contact, should terminate it after one ring.

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Yup, its not possible to handle phone settings... apple didnt gave permissions to do so....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as my knowledge you don't have controls to handle the phone.

Answer (score 3):

What Record Phone Calls does is not actually recording calls made through the native dialler. The app starts a conference-like call through which basically calls u and the other party and then record the conversation on their server side. Once done the app is pulls the info form the server and provides you with URLs to the recorded audio files. There is no call interception whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer : No you cannot control on Incoming calls